Custom TaskView to run parallel two application in single activity in Android Project
I want to create an Android Project with a single Activity. In this activity, I have two views -> left and right, each view runs an application like Samsung or Xiaomi devices. I tried to research and check many ways but nothing worked. Someone who has done it before or has some experience with this can give some ideas or solutions, thank you so much.
Link to reference:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/multi-window-support
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/fce2374/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/recents/views/TaskView.java

